# Found nil while unwrapping optional value

Tags: ios, swift, fatal-error, optional-values, unwrap

You might think: "another post about this error". 
Yes, i've been looking into this forum before writing this question and unfortunately i couldn't find something that could help, or atleast i know that this error gets on when there is a var that is not bound.

However since im quite new into this, i'd like some help.
I'm following a guide to make a simple infinite side scroller game.
So far everything went good but then i encountered this "nill" error.
The guide itself does not have this error.

So i tought maybe it could be that i use a newer version of xCode or iphone simulation. But im pretty sure its not about that.

My codings so far:

```
import Foundation

class MainScene: CCNode {
    weak var hero: CCSprite!

    func didLoadFromCCB() {
       userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touch: CCTouch!, withEvent event: CCTouchEvent!) {
       // This is the error line. I think it is caused by (applyImpulse(ccp(0, 400)) )
        hero.physicsBody.applyImpulse(ccp(0, 400)) 
    }
}
```

How can i simply fix this? 
should i make a variable with applyImpulse?
I also tried to switch between CGPoint (ccp) and CCPackage, both didn't worked.

Answer (score 3):

```
  weak var hero: CCSprite!
```

This is incredibly dangerous and likely the cause of your problem. Besides using `!`, which is almost always to be avoided, this mixes it with `weak`. That means that if *something else* stops pointing to `hero`, *this* variable becomes an implicitly unwrapped `nil`. The next time you access it, you crash.

First, get rid of the `!`. If it needs to be `weak`, use `?`. Beyond that, decide if it should really be strong. nothing you've shown here suggests that it should be weak.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reaction. 
i tried to change the "!" into a "?". It told me that it wasn't wrapped.
then i tried to switch every ! into a ? and it simply gave me the same error.

And yes, according to this tutorial it really needs to be a weak var.

_"We'll always use the format weak var codeConnectionName: Type! when completing code connections in code. We'll explain what this means later after you have some more Swift experience."_

Comment: Your tutorial is likely discussing IBOutlets (which is probably what it means by "connections"). I can't imagine any reason to use  `weak` and `!` together on a non-IBOutlet. This is not an IBOutlet, and is not connected to a storyboard or XIB. (I don't know what you mean by "it wasn't wrapped" here. I suspect you are not familiar with how optionals work?)

Comment: The wrapped part, was the error what xCode gave me. I also not that good with coding as im still a beginner. I did followed some guides that explained how optionals work, I just have to get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error code above can cause much confusion for new people because we don't know what is "optional" in swift 2.0 vs older versions of swift.  For example I was getting the same error and could not tell where the problem was.  What I found out is that I was making a call to a method using parenthesis () and in the same function I called the method without the parenthesis.  This caused the error above.  **The () are an optional component** that became optional with Swift 2.0 the way I understand it.  You have to be consistent when calling the methods otherwise the compiler will throw the "Found nil error while unwrapping an optional value".  Here is my code: The method I called inconsistently was NSDirectoryEnnumerationOptions().  This is corrected in the example I am sharing:

```
      func listFilesWithFilter() -> [String]
{
NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
    let musicUrl = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
    do{
        let fileList = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(musicUrl,includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions())
        print(fileList)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    // filter for wav files 
    do {
        let directoryUrls = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(musicUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions())
        print(directoryUrls)
        let wavFiles = directoryUrls.filter(){ $0.pathExtension == "wav"}.map{ $0.lastPathComponent}
        print ("WavFiles:\n" + wavFiles.description)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return wavFiles
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra guidance. However the example you gave, confused me. Did you miscalled _NSDirectoryEnnumerationOptions()_ and corrected it in this example? How did it look like when it was a bad code?

Comment: I made two calls to NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions() one with the parenthesis and one without and that was causing the error. So the second call was  NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.  This is where the error ties with the optional component.  The point was both options are acceptable as long as you are consistent.  Hope this helps clarify any confusion.

Comment: So i was looking to my code and everything was just "good".
However, I think that the nil problem is caused by the `weak var hero: CCSprite!` as Rob Napier said before. 
I know that a variable has to be digits, yet this tutorial gives me this?